How to treat API Result has two type response like this c#
My program calls an API which responds differently, depending on the outcome of the operation.
How can I handle this in code?
Response for success
{
"status": "OK",
"message": {
"name": "HELLO NAME",
"id": "3171024302821001",
"pob": "GARESSI SUPPA",
"dob": "01-01-1961",
"gender": "LAKI-LAKI",
"address": "BTN UNHALU BLOK C NO. 28",
"rt": "006",
"rw": "003",
"village": "KAMBU",
"district": "KAMBU",
"religion": "ISLAM",
"marital_status": "KAWIN",
"work": "PEGAWAI NEGERI SIPIL (PNS)",
"nationnality": "WNI",
"city": "KOTA KENDARI",
"province": "SULAWESI TENGGARA"
}
}


Response for fail
{
"status": "FAIL",
"message": "check input image and retry"
}

im using model linq in c#
my model c#
public class IziDataKtpOcrResponseMessage
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public IziDataKtpOcrResponseMessageData message;
}

then this my code for collecting message
            iziDataKtpOcrResponseMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IziDataResponseMessage>(iziDataKtpOcrResponse);

im using model linq and Newtonsoft.Json for this response, but when im get response "fail" my model is not support for that result.

Are the different responses returned with different HTTP status codes? If so, you could use that to determine whether the response contains an error message or could be deserialized to an appropriate object.

You may check value of the JSON field (status) before deserialization to specific class
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var jsonString = @"
{
    ""status"": ""FAIL"",
    ""message"": ""check input image and retry""
}
";

var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString);
var status = jobj["status"].ToString();
if (status == "FAIL")
{
    var errorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(jsonString);
}
else if (status == "OK")
{
    var successResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SuccessResponse>(jsonString);
}


public class Message
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string pob { get; set; }
    public string dob { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string rt { get; set; }
    public string rw { get; set; }
    public string village { get; set; }
    public string district { get; set; }
    public string religion { get; set; }
    public string marital_status { get; set; }
    public string work { get; set; }
    public string nationnality { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string province { get; set; }
}

public class SuccessResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}


ho if i take the message in success response like this?
var status = jobj["status"].ToString();

Use a discriminated union, like OneOf<> https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf
Like so:
sealed class GotPersonalDetailsResult
{
    public GotPersonalDetailsResult( String name, String id, String pob, etc... )
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Id   = id;
    }

    public String Name { get; }
    public String Id   { get; }
    // etc
}

sealed class FailureResult
{
    public FailureResult( String status, String message )
    {
        this.Status  = status;
        this.Message = message ;
    }

    public String Status  { get; }
    public String Message { get; }
}


With your service method like:
using OneOf;

public class RandomPeopleSearchClient
{
    public async Task< OneOf<GotPersonalDetails,FailureResult> > FindRandomPersonAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
    {
        using( HttpClient hc = this.hcf.CreateClient() )
        {
            // etc

            if( httpResponse.Status == 200 && isJsonResponse )
            {
                if( TryParseGotPersonalDetailsResult( out GotPersonalDetailsResult ok )  )
                {
                    return ok; // <-- This is allowed due to implicit conversion from X or Y in OneOf<X,Y>
                }
                else if( TryParseFailureResult( out FailureResult whoops )  )
                {
                    return whoops;
                }
            }

            // Otherwise, this is exceptional, so throwing is fine:

            throw new RandomPeopleSearchClientException( "Expected either a GotPersonalDetailsResult or a FailureResult but encountered an unexpected result", /* details-from-response-go-here */ );
        }
    }
}

And consumed like so:
RandomPeopleSearchClient client = ...

OneOf<GotPersonalDetails,FailureResult> result = await client.FindRandomPersonAsync();
if( result.TryPickT0( out GotPersonalDetailsResult ok, out FailureResult  failed )
{
    // Use only `ok` here
}
else
{
    // Use only `failed` here
}


Note that you're not limited to just 2 mutually-exclusive result types: the OneOf<> type supports up to 8 different types.
When you're using a 3-typed OneOf<X,Y,Z> (or more) then the TryPickT0() method returns an n-1 remainder as the second out param, thus allowing you to safely use C#'s else if without fear of accidentally dereferencing an impossible result value, like so:
OneOf<X,Y,Z> choiceOf3 = ...
if( choiceOf3.TryPickT0( out X x, out OneOf<Y,Z> yz )
{
    // Use only `x` here
}
else if( if( yz.TryPickT0( out Y y, out Z z ) )
{
    // Use only `y` here
}
else
{
    // Use only `z` here
}

It also has other FP-style methods Match and Switch which you can use to avoid having to worry about exhaustive if blocks.
